# Basic pipe does not terminate in c

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

I tried to run the following simple code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fds[2];
    pipe(fds);
    int pid1, pid2;
    if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0){
        close(fds[0]); // close read end
        dup2(fds[1], 1); // connect write end
        char *argv1[2] = {"echo", "hi"};
        execvp(argv1[0], argv1);
    }
    if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0){
        close(fds[1]); // close write end
        dup2(fds[0], 0); // connect read end
        char *argv2[2] = {"wc", "-c"};
        execvp(argv2[0], argv2);
    } 
    int status;
    waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
    printf("pid=%d terminated with status=%d\n", pid1, status);
    waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);
    printf("pid=%d terminated with status=%d\n", pid2, status);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting both the `echo` and `wc` to terminate, but the `wc` never does.
The output I get for the above code is just something like below (and the main process gets suspended waiting for the `wc` to finish).

```
pid=2802 terminated with status=0
```

> Any ideas why the second forked process doesn't finish?

---

I have checked, by trying to read from `fds[0]` after a short `sleep` at the main process, that the `wc` command has indeed read the `hi` message from the echo.

Comment: You have to close the write end.  The boiler plate is `dup2(fd[1],1); close(fd[1])`

Comment: Also, null terminate your argvs: `char *argv1[] = {"echo", "hi", NULL};`

Comment: You also need to close the write end of the pipe in the parent.  `wc` will not terminate until *all* the write sides of the pipe are closed.

Comment: Thanks, @WilliamPursell. I am not sure what you meant in your first comment, but closing the pipe at the parent did the trick :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close all of the write ends of the pipe.  There are 4 copies of that file descriptor, and `wc` is not going to terminate until all of them are closed.  The `echo` will close both of its copies when it terminates, but it's best practice to explicitly close the unused copy before you exec with:

```
dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fds[1]);
```

You need to also close that file descriptor in the parent before you call `waitpid`